# \noindent after figure not working

Tags: errors, pstricks

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.4cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\def\h{150 }
\def\w{45 }
\def\hb{8 }
\def\hd{18 }
\def\a{1 }
\def\b{1 }
\def\c{1 }
\def\d{1.5mm}
\def\N{5 }
 \centering
 \SpecialCoor
 \psset{unit=0.8mm}
  \begin{pspicture}(-25.5,-7)(23.5,150)
  \pstVerb{%
    /f {neg \h div 1 add \w mul \c dup add sub 0.5 mul} def
    /hbh 0.5 1 \hd \h div add mul def
  }
  \pspolygon(!\w 2 div neg 0)(!\w 2 div 0)(0,\h)
  \psforeach{\iA}{1,2,..,\N}{%
    \pstVerb{/z \iA\space 1 sub \b \hd add mul def}
    \pspolygon(!z f neg z)(!z f z)(!z \hd add dup f exch)(!z \hd add dup f neg exch)
    \pscircle(!0 0.5 \hd mul \iA\space 1 sub \hd \b add mul add){\d}
  }
  \pspolygon(!hbh neg \w mul \a sub \hb neg)%
            (!hbh \w mul \a add \hb neg)%
            (!0.5 \w mul \a add 0)%
            (!-0.5 \w mul \a sub 0)
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\noindent
\textsf{Bem{\ae}rkning:} Figuren er ikke i m{\aa}lestoksforholdet~$1{:}10$, men dens m{\aa}l passer i forhold til hinanden.

\end{document}
```

How do I make the code compilable when using `latex` if I want the `\noindent` after the figure?

Comment: You are probably right about the `errors` tag; I'll change it. I'm not sure if it has got anything to do with PSTricks.

Comment: I get a PostScript error, but if I change the `pspicture` environment to contain a simple command everything works; I suspect a bug in your PostScript code that makes something leak out of the picture.

Comment: @egreg I have just noticed the exact same thing. (If I use, e.g., `\psline(0,0)(1,1)`, everything is fine.) The 'problem' is that Herbert made the PSTricks code, so I natully assumed that this wasn't the problem; I'll ping him and ask.

Comment: @Herbert Do you know if my problem comes from the PSTricks code?

Comment: When I run your code, I hit with this error: `ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@
                                                  \fi \space
l.27     \pspolygon(
                    !\w 2 div neg 0)(!\w 2 div 0)(0,\h)
--- HELP ---
`

Comment: @dustin I don't get any errors. (I use an up-to-date TL2013 distribution.) Maybe Herbert can shed light on this when (if) he sees the question.

Comment: I have TL2013 as well.

Comment: After reading many questions from you, I notice that you almost always use `figure` environment and `article` document class. In my opinion, it will be better if you use `standalone` document class for each diagram, compile it to produce a single PDF output. Afterwards, you can import the diagrams (in PDF) from within your main TeX file (using `article` document class) and compile it with PDFLaTeX. Advantages: (1) you can make use of the full features of `microtype`, (2) you can reuse the code of your diagrams for other projects, (3) your main input file becomes cleaner and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  \pstVerb{
    /f { neg \h div 1 add \w mul \c dup add sub 0.5 mul } def
    /hbh 0.5 1 \hd \h div add mul def }
  }
```

that is a *global* definition of PostScript code and it is dangerous to use one character names for variables. And this is one of the cases: `/f` is defined by TeX itself. Use at least `/ff`

```
  \pstVerb{
    /ff { neg \h div 1 add \w mul \c dup add sub 0.5 mul } def
    /hbh 0.5 1 \hd \h div add mul def }
  }
```

and change it in the other expressions also to `ff`. However, something like

```
  /svend@f { ... }
```

is really safe.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `userdict begin ... end` to avoid name clash with the existing ones.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\def\h{150 }
\def\w{45 }
\def\hb{8 }
\def\hd{18 }
\def\a{1 }
\def\b{1 }
\def\c{1 }
\def\d{1.5mm}
\def\N{5 }

\SpecialCoor
\psset{unit=0.8mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-25.5,-7)(23.5,150)
    \pstVerb
    {
        userdict begin
            /f {neg \h div 1 add \w mul \c dup add sub 0.5 mul} def
            /hbh 0.5 1 \hd \h div add mul def
        end
    }%
    \pspolygon(!\w 2 div neg 0)(!\w 2 div 0)(0,\h)
    \psforeach{\iA}{1,2,..,\N}
    {%
        \pstVerb
        {
            userdict begin
                /z \iA\space 1 sub \b \hd add mul def
            end
        }%
        \pspolygon
            (!userdict begin z f neg z end)
            (!userdict begin z f z end)
            (!userdict begin z \hd add dup f exch end)
            (!userdict begin z \hd add dup f neg exch end)
        \pscircle(!0 0.5 \hd mul \iA\space 1 sub \hd \b add mul add){\d}
  }
    \pspolygon
        (!userdict begin hbh neg \w mul \a sub \hb neg end)
        (!userdict begin hbh \w mul \a add \hb neg end)
        (!0.5 \w mul \a add 0)
        (!-0.5 \w mul \a sub 0)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `userdict` can also be used by other packages. Avoid short names or use an _own_ dictionary.